# can't understand setters and getters in objective c

Tags: objective-c, setter, getter

I'm learning objective c with some online tutorials and i have a question. On this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb9-1rRjO_8&feature=player_detailpage#t=367s you can see the code i wrote here:

```
@synthesize width, height; //setters and getters

-(void) setWH:(int) w:(int) h{
    width = w;
    height = h
}
```

I don't understand why he wrote a setHW method if he already got setters and getters for width and height with @synthesize. What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is synthesising width and height, but the method you are asking about `setWH` looks lie a badly named convenience method to set the width and height in one place.

Actually, it looks quite bad, apart from not using `self.width` and `self.height` as he should do, having a `set` for something that isn't a property looks odd.

Where's the `init`?

Find a better teacher.

If you like watching videos - fire up iTunes, go to iTunesU look up C193P, which is a video set of Stanford's iPhone programming course. You'll learn a lot more correctly there.

**Edited to add**

The link to this course on iTunes is https://itunes.apple.com/gb/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

Answer (score 3):

I've had a look at the linked video and I don't think it is a very good resource for learning Objective-C.

The "setWH" method as you surmise is unnecessary and has a very confusing declaration.

```
-(void) setWH:(int) w:(int) h
```

Are `w` and `h` parameter variables or is `w:` part of the method name.  If `w:` is part of the method name then why is the parameter variable called `h`.  If `w` is a parameter variable then the method name is actually `setWH::`.

In fact both `w` and `h` ***are*** parameter variables which means you call this method as follows:

```
[obj setWH:10 :10];
```

This is not idiomatic Objective-C.

Comment: As @Abizem points out the C193P course from Stanford will give you a much better introduction to iOS development.

Comment: hmmm ... well, in all of his videos he calls method with `[obj setWH:10 :10]; ` .. so you're saying it's all wrong? maybe that's because h is using an older version of objective c? what's the proper way to call a method then? thanks

Comment: `setWH:10 :10` is a valid method name in Objective-C and will work. However, it is not idiomatic for the reason that it is confusing to read.  As my answer points out it isn't immediately obvious which parts are variables and what is method name.  A more idiomatic name would be something like `setWidth:(int)w andHeight:(int)h` although it would be better just to use `setHeight:` and `setWidth:`.